# How to run a VSTS build definition sequence locally without pushing to the repo

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

Is there a way to run the sequence of a build definition locally, without having to push changes to the repository and have the build trigger?

Currently, I have a simple build definition with only a couple of steps that I can run manually, but I plan on adding more steps to the sequence and ideally would like to run them all at once.

Similar question: *[Drone.io build locally without pushing to the repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36987332/drone-io-build-locally-without-pushing-to-the-repo)*

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to build your project locally without pushing to a remote repository, the tasks in the VSTS build definition can not be used. You need to **build each steps manually** by the related CLI or related software.

Assume in your VSTS build definition, there is the tasks as below:

- NuGet restore
- Visual Studio Build

In order to build locally, you need to use execute the below steps manually:

- Use the NuGet CLI, `nuget.exe /path/to/project restore` to work as the NuGet restore step in VSTS build.
- Use the MSBuild CLI, `msbuild /path/to/project [arguments]` or build in Visual Studio to work as Visual Studio Build step in VSTS build.